# Text effect not working properly if i add more div on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have taken a reference of the below site and i want to add text effects ie opacity gets fade on page scroll. The above code is working properly if i use the below reference as it is but if i add many div then it gets faded early not reaching the required div

http://jsfiddle.net/HsRpT/134/

Here is what i have done and the text fade effects goes early without reaching the actual div. Is there any other way of solving this problem?

```
 <div>
        fsdfdfsdfffffffffff<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <h2>Fade this in / out as scroll down</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="headerbar">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the .block text is fixed

Comment: i want to place block in any position and it's text will start fading when the page scroll is leaving the .block

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      if (scrollTop > 200) {
            $('.block').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
      }
      else {
            $('.block').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
      }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HsRpT/261/)

Comment: sorry still not working if i am adding another div. it is fading early without reaching the .block div

Answer (score 0):

```
current_div="div1";

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            current_div = scroll_content();
            console.log(current_div);
            if(current_div=="last"){
             don't fade out
          }
        });

        function scroll_content(){
             var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
            var $divs = $('section');

            var top = $.grep($divs, function(item) {
                return $(item).position().top <= winTop;
            });
            var cur=top[top.length - 1];
            return $(cur).attr('id');
        }
```

You can get the the id of the div which is going out of screen while scrolling. So you can do what ever you want to do with the divs after getting the id .

It worked for me.
Let me know if you any other query.